# WPF App with Interop - Singleton being instantiated more than once

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events, inotifypropertychanged

I am at my wits' end. Newbie to WPF so unsure where I am going wrong.

I have an MS Word Interop Add-in that captures selected text, along with various metadata. It composes my model and passes the data to it.

For this stage of development, I made my model a singleton just so that I know everything is pointing to the same reference.

Anyhow, my model is composed of a list of entries.

```
public sealed class MYMODELSingleton : ObservableObject, IMYMODEL
{




    private static MYMODELSingleton instance;

    private MYMODELSingleton()
    {
        isActive = true;

        EntryList = new List<MyEntry.IMyEntry>();
    }

    public static MYMODELSingleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if(instance == null)
            {
                instance = new MYMODELSingleton();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
    public bool isActive { get; set; }

    private List<MyEntry.IMyEntry> _entryList;

    public List<MyEntry.IMyEntry> EntryList
    {
        get { return _entryList; }
        set { _entryList = value; OnPropertyChanged("EntryList"); }
    }

    public void Add(IMYEntry mEntry)
    {
        try {
            EntryList.Add(mEntry);

            OnPropertyChanged("EntryList");
        }
        catch(ArgumentException ae)
        {
            throw ae;
        }
    }
```

ObservableObject is a custom class I made that implements INotifyPropertyChanged

```
public abstract class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Raised when a property on this object has a new value.
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises this object's PropertyChanged event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">The property that has a new value.</param>
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {

   #if DEBUG
        MessageBox.Show("Inside Event!");
   #endif

        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
  #if DEBUG
            MessageBox.Show("Event Fired!");
  #endif
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    #endregion // INotifyPropertyChanged Members

}
```

This is my ViewModel

```
public class MyEntryViewModel : ObservableObject
{

    private MYMODELSingleton activeMYMODEL= MYMODELSingleton.Instance; 


    public MyProjectModel.MYMODEL.MYMODELSingleton ActiveMYMODEL
    {
        get
        {
            return activeMYMODEL;
        }
        set
        {
            activeMYMODEL = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ActiveMYMODEL");
        }
    }

    private void ModelPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "EntryList") {
            int index = activeMYMODEL.EntryList.Count - 1;
            MyEntry = activeMYMODEL.EntryList[index];
            UpdateGui(MyEntry.Source);
        }
    }

    public void UpdateGui(SelectionState selState)
    {
        TxtDocName = selState.SelectionDocName;
        TxtDocPage = selState.SelectionPage;
        TxtDocText = selState.SelectionText;
    }  



    public MyEntryViewModel()
    {
        this.MyEntry = new MyEntry();


        activeMYMODEL.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(ModelPropertyChanged);

        //This is to notify me when the VM is created
#if DEBUG
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("ViewModelOpened!");
#endif





    }

    ~MyEntryViewModel()
    {
        activeMYMODEL.PropertyChanged -= new PropertyChangedEventHandler(this.ModelPropertyChanged);
#if DEBUG
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("ViewModel Closed!");
#endif
    } 





}
}
```

Relevant WPF Code

```
xmlns:custns="clr-namespace:MyProjectViewModel.MyEntryViewModel;assembly=MyProjectViewModel"

    Title="MyProject" Height="350" Width="525" SizeToContent="Height">
<Window.Resources>
    <custns:MyyEntryViewModel x:Key="MyProjectObj" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Name="gridEntry" DataContext="{StaticResource MyProjectObj}" >
<TextBlock x:Name="docNameTxtBx" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding TxtDocName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />
</Grid>
```

The problem is, while the entry gets added to mymodel's composed List no problem, the handler in OnPropertyChanged() always equals null. This, despite the fact that I know the ViewModel is instantiated (due to the messageboxes popping up).

FWIW, Model, ViewModel, WPF, and AddIn are all in different assemblies. The Viewmodel subscribes to the Model's event in its constructor, so why is my handler null when it's called???

---

*UPDATE*

After discussing this with a colleague, I realized the issue lies in how the MS Word ADDIN and the VM both compose the Model. Both are running in different threads and, apparently, both are holding separate instances of my Singleton! I am not sure how that is happening. I even changed my Singleton's code, making the private instance "volatile" and adding a static Object that I then lock when Instance.get() is called.

```
    private static volatile MyModelSingleton instance;
    private static object syncRoot = new Object();

    private MyModelSingleton()
    {
        isActive = true;

        EntryList = new List<MyEntry.IMyFEntry>();
    }

    public static MyModelSingleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (syncRoot)
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {

                    instance = new MyModelSingleton();
                }
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
```

Nonetheless, both the Word Interop Addin and the Viewmodel are holding separate instances. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

in the wpf code you presented, you never bind against `ActiveMYMODEL`.  becuase it is never bound in you xaml, there is never a hook into you notify property changed event created.

Comment: Thanks for responding! That, however, is not the issue. The Viewmodel captures the event from the Model, which in turn causes the VM to fire its own event that the xaml will capture from its binding, so that is not the issue.